# reduce size of WSS Log DB

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, sharepoint-2010

The mdf of my WSS Log DB has become too big and I need to reduce the size. There appears to be a lot of articles on the net about shrinking the db, which will reduce the ldf size. My problem though is the MDF is too big and I need to reduce that.

I am using MOSS 2010.

Comment: Do you mean too big in the sense that it has a lot of free space or do you have a large amount of content in it that you want to split across separate content databases?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to shrink the DB's data files. Just choose the Files->Data option when you choose to shrink instead of Database option.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete some site collection that is not in used, or you can Trim the audit logging in Sharepoint. The audit logginf takes lot of disk space.

Also you can try to create multiple content database and keep the existing database limit to as achived.

http://www.ekhichdi.com/e/INCREASE-THE-SAVE-AS-TEMPLATE-SIZE-9.html